# Prove the polynomial of nth degree is a basis for each $a$

Tags: linear-algebra

We have the vectorspace $T$ of all the polynomials such that degree$\leq n$

Prove for each $a \in R$, that the set $B_b=[{1,x-a,(x-a)^2,.......,(x-a)^n})]$ constitutes a basis for T.

I know that the polynomials $[{1,x^2,x^3,.......x^n}]$ is a basis for $P_n$. Could I use this fact to try to solve the problem?

I'm fairly new to writing math on here so I'm sorry if I've missed some symbols.

Comment: Hint: Use induction. When you can construct $1,x,x^2,x^3$ from $1,(x-a),(x-a)^2,(x-a)^3$, can you prove that $x^4$ can be constructed from $1,(x-a),(x-a)^2,(x-a)^3,(x-a)^4$?

Comment: In general, when you have a basis $1,x,x^2,...$ and you can construct these elements from other elements $1,x-a,(x-a)^2,...$, you know that $1,x-a,(x-a)^2,...$ span the space $T$. Then you are almost done (A complete answer should also prove linear independence)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick approach. Consider the function $\phi_a:T \to T$ given by $\phi_a(p(x)) = p(x-a)$. First, note that $\phi_a$ defines a linear map. Then, note that $\phi_a$ has inverse $\phi_{-a}$, since
$$
\phi_a \circ \phi_{-a} = \phi_{-a} \circ \phi_a = \operatorname{id}_T.
$$
Thus, $\phi_{a}$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces. Now, since the standard basis $[p_0,p_1,\dots,p_n]$ is a basis of $T$ (with $p_i(x) = x^i$), it follows that $[\phi_a(p_0),\phi_a(p_1),\dots,\phi_a(p_n)]$ is also a basis of $T$.